# Hibernate doesn't find entities in test

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a JDK11 project built by Maven, making full use of the JPMS introduced in Java 9.

I'd like to write integration tests, where I use an embedded H2 database. My JPA provider is Hibernate 5.4.9.

Since the H2 database is only used during testing, I first tried putting the `persistence.xml` in the test resources folder.

The problem with this is that Hibernate is looking for entities in the `test-classes` folder only and completely ignores the main classes, where my entities are. So my test fails, because it doesn't find the entities I'm trying to use.

If I copy the persistence unit declaration to the main resources folder, everything works correctly, however, I wouldn't like to have it there because Hibernate is only a test dependency and I wouldn't like to use non-existing classes.

Why is this issue suddenly happening? I never had this issue come up before (mainly with Java 8 and Hibernate 5.3).

Can I manage to have my entities detected without having to copy my `persistence.xml` to my main resources? I also wouldn't like to list my entities manually.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out. I forgot to add the following line to the `persistence-unit` declaration in my test `persistence.xml`:

`<jar-file>${project.build.outputDirectory}</jar-file>`